# Rendering array of objects in child component in vue.js

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, v-for

I'm trying to render an array in a child component but am getting a bit confused.
The props and the component are correctly declared in the parent component and I console.logged cryptoList7d (which is an array of objects) to be sure it was correctly stored and it is.

Parent component:

```
<td v-bind:key="index" v-for="(elt7d, index) in cryptoList7d">
     <item7d :elt7d="elt7d"></item7d>
</td>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <td>
            <p>{{ elt7d.name }}</p>
        </td>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "item7d",
    props: ['cryptoList7d', 'elt7d']
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

I'm not getting any error but nothing is rendering.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but a `<td>` inside of a `<div>` isn't valid html.  Then that is inside another `<td>`, which is invalid too.  `<td>` goes inside `<tr>` which goes inside `<table>`

Comment: @Dan Maybe but already did it and had no issue.... :'( Will try some different tags though. Thx anyway

Comment: Good idea, there's no benefit to using it in place of a `<div>` unless it's in a `<tr>` plus some browsers may not fix the mistake.  The rest of your code looks ok.

Comment: @Dan Tried without it but made no difference. I don't really know how consistent this is supposed to be but I thought there should always be a <div> to render the component, I think on the html side it's ignored. VSCode actually warns you about deleting this div in the parent but not in the child.

Comment: You can use a `<td>` as the root tag.  There would still be a `<td>` within a `<td>` since the loop is on one too.  Still this probably doesn't explain the missing rendering you got since most browsers will allow it

Comment: Indeed I messed up in the tags, I see that now :) I changed the whole content of the <td> to a <ul>/<li> and also tried with setting a new table with other <td> and <tr> tags but this is not the issue, it's clearly on the data side :(

Comment: Inside the loop, you could try `{{ elt7d }}` and report what you see, especially making sure there's an object with a `name` property

Comment: @Dan the object indeed has a "name" property but yeah... when I try ``` {{ elt7d }}``` in the loop I have nothing. this made me realize that maybe cryptoList7d wasn't correctly binded and it turns out this was the issue, but now I have an "architectural" issue I need to solve :D Will try to solve this one now, thanks a lot for the exterior point of view, it helped a lot!